# CSS line only working when the CSS line is duplicated

Tags: css

I'm working on a website and there's this strange "bug" where you have to place a CSS code twice in order to make it work.

For example, if I place this line in my css file, it wont work:

```
.title-styling-0:hover { color: red; }
```

But if I duplicate it like this it does work:

```
.title-styling-0:hover { color: red; }
.title-styling-0:hover { color: red; }
```

Maybe anyone faced this problem as well and found a fix or cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this really is strange. It should not be happening. Can you show us html and whole css code here?

Comment: Your CSS code has no errors. It would be hard to help you without other details. Could you provide some more?

Comment: @LuísP.A. that's not right. The example css has no errors, he could even omit that `;`

Comment: hmm.. maybe you have a DISPLAY NONE of your First Child ? then when you put another one it will show, because that's a Second child. can you please inspect the elements if you are having "display none".

Comment: try once with `!important` : `.title-styling-0:hover { color: red!important; }`

Comment: You probably have an error before the first line which causes it not to work can you show your css up to that line

Comment: @JF058 are you working using a CMS? If so which one (and version) ?

Comment: Could you show your browser dev tools and the priority of the rule in the elements panel?  It is almost impossible to help you solve this with the limited information you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
.title-styling-0:hover {color: red !important;}
```

This should fix your issue.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Yes, but now you have an `!important` rule poisoning your CSS.  I think it is better to address why a rule that should work, isn't rather than just throwing in a stop-gap.

Comment: Yes that would be better practice. But if the css is a huge file that will need time to go through, this could provide a stop-gap for now.